# How do I match the value of an array to a key of another array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, one of which is built dynamically and one which I use as a map.

The map array:

```
$social_links_map = [
    'twitter' => 'twitter-icon',
    'facebook' => 'facebook-icon'
];
```

And my dynamic array, which is just a simple list of social links:

```
$dynamic_social_links = [ 'twitter.com/me', 'facebook.com/me' ];
$social_links = explode( ',', $dynamic_social_links );
```

The `$dynamic_social_links` is an user input, as such, their **input can be wrongly typed.**

And I need to check if within my `$social_links` exists any of the `$social_links_map` keys and return the `$social_links_map` item accordingly:

```
if( !empty( $social_links ) ) {
    foreach( $social_links_map as $handle => $icon ) {
        foreach( $social_links as $social_link ) {
            if( strpos( $social_link, $handle ) ) {
                echo $handle;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't allow for "duplicate removal", nor does it look very pretty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
array_unique
```

to remove "duplicated data".

Try

```
$social_links = array_unique(explode( ',', $dynamic_social_links ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is it possible that you can allow the user to select from a list of your `$social_links_map`?

If not then the approach you are using is likely the simplest most readable way of doing this as there is no sure fire way to be able to match potentially random user input with a predefined array of options.

A couple of things to note:

As mentioned by le Mandarin, you can use array_unique to get rid of duplicates.

The other is that `strpos` will return `0` (which is falsey) if the search string (needle) is found at the very start of the context variable (haystack).

eg:

```
strpos('twitter.link/stuff', 'twitter');
```

will return 0 which is false Causing your `if` statement to fail.

instead try something like

```
if (false !== strpos('twitter.link/stuff', 'twitter')) {
```

Take note of the extra `=` in `!==`. This is necessary because you are saying "If the result is not exactly the boolean `false`.